# react loses state in if / else statement

Tags: reactjs

I am really struggling with the state in the following code. I call a function with the 'onClick'. This function has been bounded in the constructor of the component, yet for some reason the 'this.function' in the eventhandler is returned as 'undefined'.

```
render() {

if (bla) {
  (...)
  return (
    <div>Loading</div>
  )
} else: {
  return (
    <div>
      <a onClick={this.activeorArchive}><h4>Archive</h4></a>
    </div>
}}
```

The onClick calls the following function.

```
activeorArchive() {

  if (this.state.active === true) {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      assessments_list_url: prevState.assessment_list_url + 'archived=false' + "/"
    }))
    console.log(self.state.active)
  } else {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
      assessments_list_url: prevState.assessment_list_url + 'archived=true' + "/"
    }))
    console.log(self.state.active)
  }
}
```

Its not clear to me what I am doing wrong here. I've had a somewhat simular problem in the past where the return statement was part of a function itself (which was solved by converting it to a arrow function). But surely there must be a way to retain the state in a if/else statement?

### Update

As requested, the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        assessments: '',
        categories: '',
        active: true,
        assessments_list_url: "/api/assessments/",
        categories_list_url: "/api/categories/"
      };

      this.getNewUrl = this.getNewUrl.bind(this);
      this.activeorArchive = this.activeorArchive.bind(this);

    };
```

Comment: Can you show the c'tor please?

Comment: Also try to type `activeorArchive = () => { ...` as the arrow function is bounded with this.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've implemented your suggestions, but unfortunately I still get the error.

Comment: can you mention the exact error and where it points

Comment: @Jasper, will you please create a plnkr or stackblitz for this issue?

Comment: I've removed the [solved] title hack, and the addition of the solution - we prefer these to be made as answers proper. If your answer adds more than the accepted one, please feel free to add your own additional answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
activeorArchive = () => {
    const newListURL = `/api/assessments/archived=${this.state.active ? 'false' : 'true'}`;
    this.setState({assessments_list_url: newListURL});
};
```

And please let me know, if it worked for you :)